# Scrapy: How to select name of title using css selectors?

Tags: html, css, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to get data from a website and I have the following html:

```
<a class="pointy" title="Rating: 9 / 10">dont select this text</a>
<a class="pointy" title="Rating: 1 / 10">or this text</a>
```

**Q:** What css expression would I need to extract the name of the title, without knowing the actual name of the title? In this example "Rating: 9/10" and "Rating: 1/10"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.pointy::attr(title)` is a correct css selector you are looking for:

`.pointy` - node with class `pointy`
`::attr(title)` - the value of node's attribute `title`